# Merge sort: how to sort in a decreasing way?

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm interested in merge sorting. I wrote the merge step to sort in ascending order and it works (see code below). But when I try to adapt my code so that it sorts in a decreasing way, I can't do it. I wanted to reverse the i and j but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

```py
def fusion(A,low,mid,high):
    aux = [2,7,8,3,6,9]
    i = low
    j = mid+1
    for k in range(low,high,1):
        if i>mid:
            A[k] = aux[j]
            j = j+1
        elif j > high:
            A[k] = aux[i]
            i = i+1
        elif aux[i] <= aux[j]:
            A[k] = aux[i]
            i = i+1
        else:
            A[k] = aux[j]
            j = j+1
    return A
fusion([2,7,8,3,6,9],0,2,5)
```

The output is 2,3,6,7,8,9 but I would like 9,8,7,6,3,2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "reversed" variant:

```
def fusion(A, low, mid, high):
    aux = A[::-1]  # reverse A
    i = low
    j = mid + 1
    for k in range(low, high, 1):
        if i > mid:
            aux[-k - 1] = A[j]
            j += 1
        elif j > high:
            aux[-k - 1] = A[i]
            i += 1
        elif A[i] <= A[j]:
            aux[-k - 1] = A[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            aux[-k - 1] = A[j]
            j += 1
    return aux


print(fusion([2, 7, 8, 3, 6, 9], low=0, mid=2, high=5))
```

Or just reverse `range()`:

```
def fusion(A, low, mid, high):
    aux = A[::-1]  # reverse A
    i = low
    j = mid + 1
    for k in range(high, low, -1):
        if i > mid:
            aux[k] = A[j]
            j += 1
        elif j > high:
            aux[k] = A[i]
            i += 1
        elif A[i] <= A[j]:
            aux[k] = A[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            aux[k] = A[j]
            j += 1
    return aux
```

Or just ...

```
list(reversed(fusion([2, 7, 8, 3, 6, 9], 0, 2, 5)))
```